# CSS/Javascript make scrollbar inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have this custom scrollbar on my final project that i'm doing in school and the divs have a border radius of 15px, and when I put the custom scrollbar with the border radius of 15px, the scrollbar goes over the div which doesn't make it look as nice as I want it

[image]

How Can I put it inside the div so that edge won't show?

A little code of the CSS:

```
    #ruv_results, #stod2_results,#stod2bio_results, #stod3_results{
    text-align:center;


    }

.ruv_title_css, .stod2_title_css,.stod2bio_title_css, .stod3_title_css{
    font-size:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-radius:15px;
    margin-top:25px;
    width:450px;
    height:550px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
    background:#5e5e5e;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    padding-right:4px;
    padding-left:4px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-right:6px;
    margin-left:6px;

}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 15px;
    height:90%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any code the best I could offer would be experimenting with z-indexes between the two elements.  Perhaps the element with the scrollbar could sit under the containing element and hide the piece that sticks out.

Also, don't forget to put the position property on the element with z-index.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index?v=example

Comment: Hmm, It doesn't seem to work for me, I'll edit and put some code for you If that will help

Comment: try to put a position property on the elements you're applying the z-index on.  https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Comment: Could you help me? Here is the code, but I don't know how to load the Ajax Request in jfiddle jsfiddle.net/ohtd6h1j , Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: i updated your fiddle by skipping the ajax and loading the data I got straight from the API.  THere probably a better way but whatevs.  Anyway, I'm still not seeing the issue in your screenshot.  Could you update the fiddle to reproduce it?  I'm not seeing the scroll bar at all.  Hopefully i didn't delete it. ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/ohtd6h1j/1/

Comment: Yeah, It's a TV Schedule and i just switched to another one that has more description about the movies and now the scrollbar is showing and you can see It if you find the scroll bar. in one of the divs here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/ohtd6h1j/3/

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to wrap the element in another div that has some padding:

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #eee;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ddd;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.inner {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

/* Custom Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
  border-radius: 15px;
  height:90%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a iaculis enim. Fusce pellentesque mauris vitae urna sodales gravida. Pellentesque pharetra est sit amet sodales faucibus. Mauris ultrices scelerisque feugiat. Duis magna arcu, condimentum at nunc ac, aliquet congue mauris. Curabitur feugiat urna rutrum urna porttitor, facilisis lacinia nisl facilisis. Nulla porttitor, neque id varius tincidunt, nibh lectus ornare mauris, eget consectetur elit lectus quis magna. Sed fringilla semper est eu imperdiet. Phasellus accumsan orci vitae quam hendrerit venenatis. Sed rhoncus nulla non enim euismod, a pretium nisi feugiat.

    In blandit augue gravida, viverra quam vitae, malesuada sem. In mollis ante non felis accumsan ullamcorper. Cras egestas, mi ut varius elementum, libero libero ultricies nulla, vel suscipit nisi dolor vel massa. Sed non nunc nibh. Vivamus eu libero gravida, interdum justo eu, facilisis ipsum. Pellentesque accumsan justo nec odio vestibulum iaculis. Maecenas ac turpis nisi. Nullam pharetra eros at tellus convallis, sed ornare orci egestas.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This could probably work for me but I have written the html that appears in Javascript, how would I apply this there, https://jsfiddle.net/ohtd6h1j/ Here, I don't know how to load the Ajax Request with this but all the code you need is there So you can see how it kinda looks and it would be great if you could help me figure this out since I'm not the best at fixing problems